# WPF control and windows normal control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In a WinForms project there are a number of controls such as `MenuStrip`, `OpenFileDialog`, `SaveFileDialog`.

After a quick look,  I can't seem to see the equivalents for these controls in the WPF toolbox.

Is there any way to gain access to these or do they exist in another form?

Comment: Exactly what controls are missing?  Could you elaborate.  I have found nothing that cannot be done in WPF that could be done in WinForms.

Comment: It might help if you said which controls you were missing - their WPF equivalents are probably around somewhere.

Comment: Yup, WPF sucks. Use WinForms instead. Is that what you want to hear? I don't see how this is a real question.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Look at his other questions today... He needs to discover Google or a book on WPF maybe

Comment: @Matt: Yeah, I just noticed that. Or go back to WinForms. Whichever's easier. I'm sure there is an online tutorial *somewhere* that discusses the differences between WPF and WinForms, but I don't need the rep bad enough to Google for it myself.

Comment: The question is just plain bad.  He's assuming you can't use the OFD/SFD in WPF just because you can't drag it onto the design surface and have a little icon appear at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different resources you can use for finding the type of control you need.

Have you looked in the **[WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/)**?

Have you investigated any **third party control vendors**?

([Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf.aspx), [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/index.xml), [ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioWPF/), [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf.aspx))

---

[Here's an excellent link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750559.aspx) comparing the WinForms and WPF control equivalents.

You'd probably recieve a more detailed answer if you gave specifics as to which control you're looking for.

Comment: like toolstrip,menustrip,print-preview,open dialog,save dialog etc. i just want to know is it possible to use normal windows contols in WPF project.yes or no.

Comment: @Thomas Please see my edit - there are equivalents for all of those except the `PrintPreviewDialog`.

Comment: Try Google.  "open dialog wpf" and what do you know the top link provides you with your answer.  Just like every other question you have posted today.  SO is for help with issues, I don't think it is here to answer your 500 super basic WPF fundamental questions...

Comment: Also, don't forget Infragistics. Used them for 5 years or so now, they're intuitive and powerful. Support is also excellent, recommended :)

Comment: @Tom Whoops, knew I forgot one. Will add them on.

Comment: @Daniel exactly why can't you use the PPD in a WPF app?

Answer (score 1):

you can add a winforms host into the project but which controls are you after as the wpf does have a decent amount of controls and generally does more in the ui department (but pays in speed usually)